# An appetizing affix riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a friend of campfires, missing its tail.
> My infix is natural, useful and alluding to its state.
> My suffix, unless prefixed, is made of wood and missing its core.
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [Smorgasbord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sm%C3%B6rg%C3%A5sbord)

My prefix is a friend of campfires, missing its tail.

> **Smor**, which is [S'more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%27more) without its tail "e"

My infix is natural, useful and alluding to its state.

> **Gas** - natural gas is a naturally occurring hydrocarbon gas which is indeed very useful (for cooking, for example) and its state of matter is also *gas*.

My suffix, unless prefixed, is made of wood and missing its core.

> **Bord** which is *board* without its core "a". The prefix part, I think, refers to things like *plaster*board which are not wood.

Title

> A smorgasbord (either literally or figuratively) is indeed appetizing